# how to strip out part of a string in a javascript array

Tags: javascript

I have several arrays that are built similar to this:

```
exampleArray=new array(
"A01 - Blah Blah Blah",
"A01A - Blah Blah Blah Blah")
```

I'm using these Arrays to populate options in a form and I need to strip out everything after the first space(i.e. " - Blah Blah Blah") for the values of a given option.  The options and values are currently being generated with this code:

```
for(i=0; i<optionStepTwo.length; i++) {
    elementStepTwo.options[elementStepTwo.options.length] = 
            new Option(optionStepTwo[i], optionStepTwo[i]);
};
```

Comment: so A01 would be the option value, and Blah blah blah woul dbe the displayed text? If they're going into an arra, why not store the two parts in separate elements? This'd save you having to use string operations to yank them apart again later.

Comment: Actually that would help, I'm just not sure how to write the array that way.

Comment: `var x = [['A01', 'blahblahblah'], ['a01a', 'blahblah']];` which'd make `x[1][0]` be `a01a`.

Comment: Awesome, I'll have to play around with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) after " "(space), like:

```
var desiredOption = optionStepTwo[i].split(" ")[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

To truncate a string at the first space:

```
var myStringBeforeFirstSpace = myString.split(" ")[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to split only at the first space.

```
var string = 'A01A - Blah Blah Blah Blah';
var firstSpace = string.indexOf(' ');
alert(string.substr(0, firstSpace));​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/g6csw/)**